# Testing recurring payment in Dibs (in moneyscripts) module for Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, dibs

I know you have pretty strict rules here, so I hope this question is OK.

I am new to Drupal and am working with a website. We are going to offer our users 1 free test month, and after this we will charge a monthly fee. This far we've set up a few test accounts, and using the test/dummy cards provided by Dibs it works for the first month, but after one month when the first **actual** payment is supposed to be charged it gets denied. 
I have been in contact with Dibs and they have tried charging manual one-time ammounts from our site, using the test cards and this seems to work fine.

*My question is*:Is there any way to fix so that I can make manual API-calls to parse from Drupal, without having to wait the full first month to test if everything is fine? I am not familiar with the structure and don't know where to change anything.

Also if someone has any other ideas of what the problems might be, all advice are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove below it will go live and if you add, it input type it will again set to test mode.

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="1">
```